# How to convert the date format from mmddyy to mm/dd/yyyy in csv column and save back to the same column in shellscript

Tags: shell, unix

I have a csv file with date column in mmddyy (ex: 090718). I need to convert it to mm/dd/yyyy(ex: 09/07/2018) and save back to same column in csv using shell script

Comment: Read the file line per line.  Extract the date field.  Modify it using `sed` or `awk`.  Write the new line in another file.  Keep your source intact.   Get started, do some reasearch, return here if you have specific issues (see [ask] and [mcve]).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your problem is simply to reformat your date string in the following way: isolate groups of 2 digits and add "20" before the last group (the date on 2 digits is anyway insufficient to guess the century).

Assuming also the date column is among others separated by a  `;`.

For instance `input.csv` is

```
data_l1c1;110918;data_l1c3
data_l2c2;090718;data_l2c3
```

Then a simple GNU `sed` replacement would be:

```
sed -i -E "s/;(.{2})(.{2})(.{2});/;\1\/\2\/20\3;/g" input.csv
```

- `;(.{2})(.{2})(.{2});` finds 3 groups of 2 characters between `;`
- The replacement string is `;\1\/\2\/20\3;` Each group found is labeled : \1 refers to the first group of two digits found, ..., \3 to the third. Per your problem statement each of these group should appear separated by a / (the slashes must be protected, so they appear as `\/`), and the last group \3 preceded by "20".
- The -i says "in-place" so replaces the expression found by the replacement string in the source (the file `input.csv` is modified).

Comment: I would ensure you are capturing digits, so you don't disrupy another field with 6 characters: `sed -r 's#;([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2});#;\1/\2/20\3;#'`

Comment: Thanks. If i have more than one date fields in my input, how can i achieve this for specific column?